# compare - is line greater or less than previous in bash

Tags: bash, awk

Hello and thanks for reading. This seems very simple, All I need is a for loop.

I have a huge data file that is

```
212
265
2321
12
183
```

etc etc

All I need is to append ">" at the end of every line if the value is smaller than the previous and a "<"1f the value is smaller than previous. So my desired output would be

```
212 <
265 >
2321 > 
12 <
183 >
```

This code

```
awk '{if ($1<prev); print ("<"); prev=$0}' input > output
```

just gives < for all the lines.

How to accomplish this in awk or any other bash?

Comment: What should be output if the 2 values are equal? Add that to your sample input/output. Also explain why the first lines sign is < rather than >.

Comment: You have an extra `;` between `if` and `print` so the `print` becomes unconditional.

Comment: You also never print `>` anywhere in the code.

Comment: They will never be the same, so no issue for equal ones in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $0, ($0 > prev ? ">" : "<"); prev=$0}' file
212 >
265 >
2321 >
12 <
183 >
```

or maybe this meets your requirements better for handling the first value in the file:

```
$ awk '{print $0, ((NR > 1) && ($0 > prev) ? ">" : "<"); prev=$0}' file
212 <
265 >
2321 >
12 <
183 >
```

wrt why your code didn't work, you wrote:

```
{if ($1<prev); print ("<"); prev=$0}
```

which is:

```
{if ($1<prev); # Test $1 vs prev but then do nothing based on the result of the
               # comparison since the semi-colon terminates the conditional block
print ("<");   # Always print a "<" symbol for every input line
prev=$0}       # Set prev to the current lines value
```